# Issue updating state on re-deployed Corda Enterprise App

Tags: corda

I have encountered an issue when re-deploying a Corda Enterprise app after changing some ledger code and trying to update a state created by the old deployment. Initially I encountered a Notary issue caused by the following TransactionBuilder constraint:

```
    require(notary == this.notary) { "Input state requires notary \"$notary\" which does not match the transaction notary \"${this.notary}\"."
```

This was solved by using the NotaryChangeFlow. An example of my usage is below:

```
        val inputNotary = inputState.state.notary
        if(inputNotary != newNotary) {
            subFlow(NotaryChangeFlow(inputState, newNotary))
        }
```

However, I am now getting the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know about O=Party, L=Sydney, C=AU
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowMessagingImpl.sendSessionMessage(FlowMessaging.kt:65) ~[corda-node-3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.ActionExecutorImpl.executeSendInitial(ActionExecutorImpl.kt:177) [corda-node-3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.ActionExecutorImpl.executeAction(ActionExecutorImpl.kt:75) [corda-node-3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.interceptors.MetricActionInterceptor.executeAction(MetricInterceptor.kt:31) [corda-node-3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.TransitionExecutorImpl.executeTransition(TransitionExecutorImpl.kt:51) [corda-node-3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.interceptors.HospitalisingInterceptor.executeTransition(HospitalisingInterceptor.kt:54) [corda-node-3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.interceptors.DumpHistoryOnErrorInterceptor.executeTransition(DumpHistoryOnErrorInterceptor.kt:46) [corda-node-3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.interceptors.MetricInterceptor.executeTransition(MetricInterceptor.kt:23) [corda-node-3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.interceptors.FiberDeserializationCheckingInterceptor.executeTransition(FiberDeserializationCheckingInterceptor.kt:50) [corda-node-3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.processEvent(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:133) [corda-node-3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.processEventsUntilFlowIsResumed(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:162) [corda-node-3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.suspend(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:396) [corda-node-3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowSessionImpl.sendAndReceive(FlowSessionImpl.kt:64) [corda-node-3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowSessionImpl.sendAndReceive(FlowSessionImpl.kt:71) [corda-node-3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.core.flows.DataVendingFlow.sendPayloadAndReceiveDataRequest(SendTransactionFlow.kt:81) [corda-core-3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.core.flows.DataVendingFlow.call(SendTransactionFlow.kt:59) [corda-core-3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.core.flows.DataVendingFlow.call(SendTransactionFlow.kt:42) [corda-core-3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.subFlow(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:281) [corda-node-3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:312) [corda-core-3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.core.flows.AbstractStateReplacementFlow$Instigator.getParticipantSignature(AbstractStateReplacementFlow.kt:118) [corda-core-3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.core.flows.AbstractStateReplacementFlow$Instigator.collectSignatures(AbstractStateReplacementFlow.kt:102) [corda-core-3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.core.flows.AbstractStateReplacementFlow$Instigator.call(AbstractStateReplacementFlow.kt:78) [corda-core-3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.core.flows.AbstractStateReplacementFlow$Instigator.call(AbstractStateReplacementFlow.kt:60) [corda-core-3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.subFlow(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:281) [corda-node-3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:312) [corda-core-3.1.jar:?]
at com.administration.ledger.flow.MemberUpdateFlow$Initiator.call(MemberFlow.kt:104) [administration-ledger-0.1.jar:0.1]
at com.administration.ledger.flow.MemberUpdateFlow$Initiator.call(MemberFlow.kt:80) [administration-ledger-0.1.jar:0.1]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:225) [corda-node-3.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:51) [corda-node-3.1.jar:?]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) [quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) [quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) [quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) [quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_131]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
```

I was wondering if anyone has seen this error before / knows what could be causing it. It seems related to the transaction referencing the original O=Party, L=Sydney, C=AU Party which was a participant in the initial state creation. This Flow worked fine in Corda OS but is causing problems after migrating to Enterprise.

Comment: Left an answer below. Still asking around to identify best practice for handling this situation.

Comment: Sorry I am unable to see the answer provided. Not sure if its just me?

Comment: I deleted it. I'd misunderstood what you were asking (I thought you'd changed the nodes on the network).

Comment: Ah k, no problem. I did a bit more investigating today and I still can't seem to find the issue. Just confirming the ./gradlew deployNodes command is the correct one to re-deploy nodes after changes are made and that there are no extra steps to whitelist anything (considering AlwaysAllowContractConstaints is enabled)? I haven't tested the process using an external H2 database so maybe it is something to do with the migration to Postgres? If you need anymore info, just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say in your comment above:

> Just confirming the ./gradlew deployNodes command is the correct one
>   to re-deploy nodes after changes are made

This is incorrect. Re-running `deployNodes` will create a new set of nodes with a new set of certificates. This is why you're getting exceptions of the form `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know about O=Party, L=Sydney, C=AU`.

You should update the CorDapp using the following process instead:

- Put the node in flow-drain mode, as per the instructions [here](https://docs.corda.net/upgrading-cordapps.html#flow-drains)
- Once flow-drain is complete, turn off the node
- Build the new CorDapp JAR by following the instructions [here](https://docs.corda.net/cordapp-build-systems.html#creating-the-cordapp-jar)
- Install the new CorDapp JAR by following the instructions [here](https://docs.corda.net/cordapp-build-systems.html#installing-the-cordapp-jar)
- Restart the node

Comment: In the example I provided, the ledger nodes are exactly the same. Would this then be a case of bad design on my part, as in a ledger that has been re-deployed should not be able to update a state created by the old version even though the parties are the same? If so, is there a way around this? What if a member joins and a state is created. Then a few month down the line, a new version of the ledger code is deployed, how can this member data be updated?

Comment: Hmm, I misunderstood. You're saying the network has remained the same, you just turned off a node, updated the CorDapp, and turned it on again?

Comment: Ye that’s correct, the CorDapp was updated and the whole network restarted. I am using Postgres if that makes any difference. However, I used the exact same process in OS and it worked fine. AlwaysAcceptAttachmentConstraint is also enabled.